# Migrating from validate-jwt to validate-azure-ad-token policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, azure-api-management

I've previously been using the `validate-jwt` policy successfully in a lot of projects. I would like to try out the new `validate-azure-ad-token` policy instead.

I changed one of my policies from:

```xml
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid.">
    <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    <required-claims>
        <claim name="azp" match="all">
            <value>{{portal-clientId}}</value>
        </claim>
    </required-claims>
</validate-jwt>
```

To:

```xml
<validate-azure-ad-token header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized. Access token is missing or invalid." tenant-id="{{tenant-id}}">
    <client-application-ids>
        <application-id>{{portal-clientId}}</application-id>
    </client-application-ids>
</validate-azure-ad-token>
```

The former works without any issues, but I just can't get the latter to work. The named value `portal-clientId` in both policy snippets above correspond to the applicationId of both the app registration and the enterprise app.

As you can see from the former, the value is in the `azp` claim. From jwt.ms, it sounds like this should be the correct claim for the new policy as well:

> The application ID of the client using the token. The application can act as itself or on behalf of a user. The application ID typically represents an application object, but it can also represent a service principal object in Azure AD.

I've read both the [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateAAD) and the [article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-developer-community-blog/introducing-a-better-way-to-integrate-azure-ad-with-api/ba-p/3671864) introducing the new feature, but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. When tracing, the newer policy has the following to say:

```
validate-azure-ad-token (3.470 ms)
{
    "message": "Azure AD JWT Validation Failed: ValidationFailed."
}
```

Are there some hidden expectations in the new policy? My issuer in the token is `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/v2.0`.

Viewing logs in application insights connected to this API yields no more useful information than the trace, even when activating verbose logging.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use API inspector to troubleshoot this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Source: I am on the Azure API Management team and responsible for the APIM policy implementations).

Short version: Revert back to using validate-jwt (for now).

There are two issues here.

1. Your two statements are not equivalent.  The client application ID is exposed in JWT as an audience.  You are correct on the validate-azure-ad-token version and wrong on the validate-jwt version.
2. There is a current bug (that we are working on and will be fixed "soon") whereby the underlying library we are using for Azure Active Directory is not validating v2.0 tokens.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I think I'm a bit confused about the terminology for the `validate-azure-ad-token` then, as it has a section for audience as well, but that is not required whereas `client-application-ids` is required. I don't particularly care about the client in this case, because I know if it can receive a token it has the right to access my APIs. As far as I understand, `aud` is always what is most important since that determines the receiving end, in this case my APIs backend. I am using 2.0 tokens so reverted to `validate-jwt`.

Comment: I suspect you are taking a short cut around the in-built security for the JWT.  When using Azure AD, you would create two applications - one for the service (which exposes an API) and another for the client (which has permission to access the API).  When you are doing either a validate-jwt or validate-azure-ad-token, you want to check that the JWT provided by the client is correct without saying anything about what APIs are available.  Authorization should remain with the backend service.  In API Management, you are just saying "I expect this client to be accessing this API"

Comment: I have >2 principals, one representing a single page application and additionally for multiple different APIs all exposed in APIM. Different APIs validate different audiences, but the client is the same in almost all cases (my SPA, different based on environment only). I then assign access to users to the SPA principal using roles I have defined both on the SPA and API principals. I then know that to get a token for any of the APIs, the user must have been assigned. Am I doing something wrong in my setup here?

Comment: How does this work when you have many client applications calling a common API. Do you have to list all of the client IDs from the calling applications?!

Comment: @Nick yes, just a list of allowed client applications (`azp` claims)

Answer (score 0):

```
After spending more than 4 hours trying to figure the the correct Policy finally it works.
The policy should be as follows:-

  <validate-azure-ad-token tenant-id="521c22d3-fb21-4c0f-8ff6-*****">
            <audiences>
                <audience>api://29f66c25-56c9-474f-b298-******</audience>
            </audiences>
            <client-application-ids>
                <application-id>7d2e7430-bc1b-44e6-8f63-*****</application-id>
            </client-application-ids>
        </validate-azure-ad-token>
```

You can extract the application ID and audience from the token, just take any generated token and decode it.